# Change Culture Basicframe.Webcontrols.BasicDatePicker

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am using **Basicframe.Webcontrols.BasicDatePicker.dll** for the datepicker. Currently it works fine for the en-US Culture which is by default. I want to use this datepicker with Swedish Culture.(sv-SE)

Please Help Regarding That.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Not sure if this works with Basicframe, but you can override the master culture for any page. Insert this in your Global.asax file:
    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo cInf = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("sv-SE", false);
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cInf;
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cInf;
    }

Answer (score 1):

You can override master culture for all pages your site serves. Add this to `Global.asax`.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    // specify any culture you want
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo cInf = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ru-RU", false);
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cInf;
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cInf;
}
```